# IBM CPLEX ERROR "Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: Problem accessing the Excel file"

Tags: cplex, opl

I am actually new to CPLEX and currently learning how to read my data from the excel file. Unfortunately, every time I tried to create my own configuration, even the Oil samples, the error messages always appear stating that "Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: Problem accessing the Excel file". I have tried to find some answers through the forum but still have no idea what is the problem with it.

Can anyone please give me recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Which CPLEX version ? And which excel  version do you use ?

Comment: I assume that you haven't got the Excel file open in Excel at the same time. Excel effectively locks the file so nothing else can use it.